# need to click 2 times to lose focus

Tags: javascript, focus, onblur

In my form, I have some fields on which I have applied `onblur` event. Problem is if I click on save directly after entering some field, save does not get called. I need to click twice.
For more clarifications, refer to steps below and code snippet is also attached.

1) Enter some value in input box
2) Lose focus by either tabing out or clicking somewhere else on screen
3) it works fine and function triggerOnBlur gets invoked
4) now enter some value in input box again
5) straight away click on save button, without clicking anywhere else
6) function triggerOnBlur gets invoked, but in order to click save button, I need to click on save.

I want to get it done in one click..

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function triggerOnBlur()
{
alert("onblur event triggered");
}

function triggerSaveButton()
{
alert("save button");
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form>
<input type = "text" onblur = "triggerOnBlur()" />
<input type = "submit" value = "Save" onclick = "triggerSaveButton()" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: My guess would be that the alert in the onBlur event is moving focus away from the button, so the onClick event doesn't get run. What happens if your triggerOnBlur() method does something that doesn't snatch focus?

Comment: hey. thxx gareth for reply.yes u r right. actually in my real implemetation, instead of alert box, i need to have ajax call over there but it is doing same thing as alert box, may be because ajax call also removes the focus. so any suggestions what could be done??

Answer (score 1):

You could always do something like:

```
function triggerSaveButton()
{
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input"), input = null;
    for(var i = 0, len = inputs.length; i < len; i++) {
        input = inputs[i];
        if(input.type == "text" && input == document.activeElement) {
            input.blur();
        }
    }
    // onblur triggered, now continue with function
    alert("save button");
}
```

Comment: no.. it didn't work :( may be because at the end, it loses focus

Comment: Seems to work on my end, when you click save with an `input` that has `:focus`, it will fire the `onblur` event of that `input`. Isn't that what you were asking for? Just run the rest of your code after the `for` loop.

Comment: Don't use `alert` to test your code, it will break out of the `function` @TarunMadaan try `console.log()` or some form of `innerHTML` output.

Comment: thxx for reply faino.. onblur event do get fire even in the original code snipped , but i need to click save twice in order to trigger save function

Comment: With the code I have provided, you only need to click the save button once and it will fire both events. I've tested it on multiple browsers and multiple times. Get rid of the alerts, use console.log() or some other form the check your firing, also maybe try adding `onsubmit="return(false);"` to your `form` tag for testing purposes; to see that I speak the truth.

Answer (score 1):

Because your `alert()` break the `click` event, `click event` need you release mouse key on the button, if you must use `alert()`, you may use `onmousedown` event, look at this example

http://jsfiddle.net/3w8VM/

Comment: Thanks wing for reply, but in your example save function gets invoked first then blur event which is not desired but oderwise